# How to map "Configuration Editor" items with "Feature Delegation" items?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-8

In IIS Manager, I can tweak the "**Feature Delegation**" items.

But "**Feature Delegation**" items have friendly names, and sometimes no clue to which "**Configuration Editor**" items they belong to.

I would like to know which "**Configuration Editor**" items belongs to which "**Feature Delegation**" items ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Configuration Editor allows you to view and modify configuration settings for various IIS components. It provides a graphical interface to access and modify configuration settings stored in the web.config file or applicationHost.config file.
The configuration editor organizes configuration settings into hierarchies. Each setting corresponds to a specific feature or module in IIS, and these settings are grouped in different sections according to the feature they belong to.

Feature delegation allows you to delegate control of specific IIS functions to different users or groups. By default, server-level settings are locked down, but you can selectively delegate control of individual features to specific users or groups. This allows administrators to distribute administrative tasks and responsibilities among different individuals or teams.

The IIS Feature Delegate item displays the names of UI features in IIS Manager, these "friendly" names may not directly correspond to configuration settings in the Configuration Editor. To determine which "Configuration Editor" items correspond to specific "Function Delegation" items, you need to consult the relevant IIS documentation to understand the IIS configuration schema.

To understand the configuration structure of IIS, you can refer to the series of official documents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/

For example, you want to know which Configuration Editor section corresponds to Authentication-Anonymous in Feature Delegation. You can see in the documentation that settings related to anonymous authentication will be found under the "system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication" section.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I searched which "**Feature Delegation**" grants rights on the "*system.webServer/serverRuntime*", without any success...

Comment: Feature delegation settings delegate specific functions to different levels in IIS (server, site, or application). But there is no user interface that lets you configure the <serverRuntime> element for IIS. The <serverRuntime> element is configured directly in the configuration file and is not part of the Feature delegation.

Comment: Interesting and useful. How did you manage to know and be sure that "The <serverRuntime> element is configured directly in the configuration file and is not part of the Feature delegation" ?

Comment: You can learn about these by consulting the official documentation and looking for knowledge resources. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/serverruntime